# Target IE in the CSS code

Tags: css, internet-explorer, target

I know how to target IE, but that's only in HTML (which means I need to create another CSS file for IE bugs). Is their anyway, how I can implement the fixes in the same CSS file. This mean I target IE with CSS code?

Comment: I would suggest avoiding this; write a CSS specifically for IE and reference it from the desired page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with these hacks

**For example:**

```
selector {
 color: red; /* all browsers, of course */
 color : green\9; /* IE8 and below */
 *color : yellow; /* IE7 and below */
 _color : orange; /* IE6 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to conditional comments/code in CSS.   The only thing you could do there are the old CSS hacks -- that people struggled with before conditional comments became known.

You can make CSS hacks work, for a bit, but it's not a smart or robust approach.

Recommended approach:

1. Always start with a CSS reset.  Here's a good one: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css
2. If at all possible, get your boss or client to realize that IE6 support is not cost-effective.
3. Design HTML and CSS with an eye for IE bugs, as much as possible.  EG, float-problems, height and margin problems, etc.
4. For those few things that still need different CSS in IE, putting them in a conditionally-included, separate CSS file really is the simplest, most robust approach.   The bonus is it doesn't penalize decent browsers one bit.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code, precede your selectors with something that only IE will recognize. Examples of selecting `<div>` elements in IE6 and IE7:

IE6 only: `* html div`

IE7 only `*:first-child+html div`

A comprehensive list can be found here: http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Comment: @reisio - do you have anything to offer, such as a more comprehensive list?